# Looking for third party SerialPort solution

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I'm looking for a third party Serial Port solution (commercially or open-source are equally welcome). There are some known bugs in .NET Serial Port class that gives me all sorts of threading errors. Does any know of any good third party solution that works for C# WPF application?

[EDITED]
I have encountered similar problems to [this](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html)

Comment: What kind of known bugs are you dealing with? We use the .NET `SerialPort` for an extremely threaded mission-critical application and have no problems with it. In fact, it is used in 3 places for 3 different protocols, and still no issues.

Comment: @drharris, take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421515/i-o-operation-has-been-aborted-exception-for-serialport
have you tried turning on and off serial port very fast for 10 times? It will crash

Comment: Why are you needing to turn it on and off very fast? Typically, if you're using a serial port it is dedicated to your application, so why not reserve it for the entire lifecycle of your program? Allocating/Deallocating I/O is not a trivial operation and constant open/close behavior really is not typical usage. The `Close()` behavior (indeterminate amount of time) is a known fact, but it is not a bug.

Comment: @drharris - just wanted to let you know I was having a similar problem reading from a truck scale. I was only opening the port when the scaling was taking place and closing/disposing when I was done. I read about the MS "bugs" and came looking for another solution. I wrote a wrapper around the serial port that stays open with the application and it works much better now. I even got out of cross thread calls. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: I've encountered some issues with SerialPort. The com port or virtual com port usb device will disappear from device manager if not open/close properly on PC.
I open the port while the device is still booting (usb drive is awake but the app is not executed), I send a command and of course it will give me timeout exception cause the core app is not executed yet. But if I close the port, it will take time, around 30~40 secs to close. And if I open it too quick after closed, the open procedure will freeze until I unplug the device. And when I plug it back, the device is not detected any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB or RS-??? (232, 435, etc)?

Just googling a little:

Open source:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/serialportnet/

Comercial:

- http://www.marshallsoft.com/serial-communication-library.htm
- http://www.zylsoft.com/serialportnet.htm

Answer (score 2):

try http://www.commstudio.com/commstudio