# C# .NET serial port opens and immediately closes at 115200

Tags: c#, .net, io, serial-port, port

I have a funny problem...I have some software that is working with lots of computers (over 100)  It connects to a serial port using the .NET serial port class.
The software must connect at 115200 for all the features to work.
Now normally there is no issue.  However, I have two computers that cannot connect at 115200.  They can connect at 19200 or 9600 but not 115200.  In addition, they can connect at 115200 with a few other pieces of software without issues!
This is what is happening when looked at with a serial port sniffer:

```
 19200 Baud Trace:
```

[29/04/2018 19:05:26] - Open port COM3

[29/04/2018 19:05:26]Changed baudrate: 19200

[29/04/2018 19:05:26]Disabled RTS

[29/04/2018 19:05:26]Disabled DTR

[29/04/2018 19:05:26]Changed line control: Databits 8, Parity none, StopBits 1

[29/04/2018 19:05:26]Changed flow control: ControlHandShake 0x00, FlowReplace 0x00, XonLimit 55546, XoffLimit 55546

[29/04/2018 19:05:26]Changed baudrate: 19200

and this is at 115200

```
 115200 Baud trace:
```

[29/04/2018 19:10:43] - Open port COM3

[29/04/2018 19:10:43] - Close port COM3

[29/04/2018 19:10:43] - Open port COM3

[29/04/2018 19:10:43] - Close port COM3

Does anyone have any ideas what is happening?

Here is the code:

```
            port = new SerialPort(comport, baud);

            port.ReadTimeout = 20;
            port.Open();
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd test a third-party serialport replacement before spending too much time on this issue. Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441790/looking-for-third-party-serialport-solution) for alternatives. A simple test application should be sufficient.

Comment: Actually I have used the .NET serial port class for 5 years in my applications.  I have over 2000 users in a high RF (radio frequency) environment and the app is heavily multi-threading.  I never had a single issue until today

Comment: Exactly why I'd try an alternative just to rule out SerialPort being the issue for these two machines instead of spending a ton of time on investigation. Esp. since another client on the same machine doesn't have the connection issue, otherwise it would be easy to blame the modem/physical connection/microwave oven. Try pull down the mono sources and debug the SerialPort-implementation there (if they have one).

Comment: I guess, it's an option depending how much issues exist for the integration.  For now I'll be entering some debug code..

Comment: Do you have a `Try` `Catch` around the code?  What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Ok, the program is solved.  The Try-Catch on the port.Open immediately reported that the maximum baud rate for the device is 23800.  Therefore it could not open the port.  On further investigation, it seems that the users installed the Windows Universal Driver for the serial port.  With .NET 4.0 it gives the error.  Other libraries its doesn't. Installing  the regular Windows driver fixes the issue.